# How could I configure default deployment device for Xamarin projects in Visual Studio Community for Mac?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, ios-simulator

When I open a Xamarin project in Visual Studio Community for Mac (version 8.9.2), the default deployment device is always **iPod Touch** (simulator).

This is the first device in the list of simulators. How could I configure a different device to be the default one?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do this.  You can delete simulator images you don't need from XCode

Comment: Good point @Jason, at least now I have an iPhone as the default device after deleting the iPod. Not the one I want, but better than before.